# Which known theorems of Lie algebras are still valid for Leibniz algebras?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, big-list, leibniz-algebras

[Leibniz algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_algebra) can be seen as a non-commutative generalization of Lie algebras. Thus, it is common to see a lot of papers which topic is about a generalization of a classic theorem of Lie algebras to Leibniz algebras. 
For instance, (1) gives a generalization of Engel's theorem to Leibniz algebras.

Is there a survey of which known theorems of Lie algebras are still valid (and also **not** valid) for general Leibniz algebras? If not, could we make a community wiki to gather examples? 
I think it would be a nice idea to put these examples in the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_algebra) of Wikipedia.

(1): Ayupov, Sh A., and B. A. Omirov. "On Leibniz algebras." Algebra and operator theory. Springer, 1998. 1-12.

Comment: One example: if a Leibniz algebra (over any commutative ring) admit a grading in $\mathbf{Z}$ such that $\mathfrak{g}_n=0$ for all $|n|\ge n_0$ for some $n_0$ and $\mathfrak{g}_0=0$, then $\mathfrak{g}$ is nilpotent. (See my answer to  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90964/lie-algebra-admitting-some-hyperbolic-automorphism-is-nilpotent )

Comment: Note that this nilpotency result is trivial for positive gradings ($\mathfrak{g}_n=0$ for all $n<0$ and all $n\ge n_0$), but the latter trivially holds for all algebras (module + bilinear law) while the former doesn't, with simple counterexamples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of such a survey, but a number of important properties are established in D.W.Barnes, [Some theorems on Leibniz algebras](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2010.489529), Comm. In Alg. 39, 2463-2472,
(2011) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2821724)), and
D. W. Barnes, [On Levi’s theorem for Leibniz algebras](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-levis-theorem-for-leibniz-algebras/048FA86D849F1552EB9D4F4B93A12AA6), Bull. Aust. Math. Soc. 86,
184-185, (2012) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2979978)).